# Use -force_load with a Swift Package Manager package?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

My team produces an SDK, and some of our clients consume the SDK as a SPM package. The SDK is in Objective-C, so we recommend to our clients to add `-ObjC` to other linker flags.

We have a client who uses SPM who doesn't want to use `-ObjC`, so we want to recommend using `-force_load`  instead. Is there a way I can access the file path of where the SPM package ends up, in such a way that I can use it with `-force_load`? For example, it looks like the fetched package ends up at

`/Users/<me>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FakeProject12-dyydlcfzdrhdvdchxphueqwmewfi/SourcePackages/checkouts/<package>/Sources/<SDK>.xcframework`

Is there any way for me to access this path? Using `$(DERIVED_DATA_DIR)` only gives me `/Users/<me>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`. Is there way for me to get the path that I could use with `-force_load`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach is to eliminate the need for `-ObjC` (or `-force_load`) all together by adding references to category files. See this [example](https://github.com/google/promises/pull/221/files).